# Open my app (with custom params) from Fb Messenger message

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, native, messenger

I'm wondering how emulate the behaviour of Spotify app has working with Fb Messenger. With Spotify you can share songs in Messenger friends conversation and then your friend can open a link, through a "Open" button in msg layout, to that song in Spotify.

Another cool thing is that If you haven't installed Spotify the song message has a "Install" button that guide you to Apps Store.
I know about Messenger optimized apps but I don'f find this specific behaviour in docs.

It would be great somebody could enlighten to me what components of Messenger/Fb SDK use for accomplish that.

Thanks, 
Ignacio.

Comment: I think you’re looking for App Links. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks, http://applinks.org/

Comment: mmhh looks promising, thanks you. I will back here with a response once I have tested this.

Comment: @CBroe at the end I dropped deep linking with Fb App Link and now I go with branch.io One reason is cause I need links with custom params and the api for create them is deprecated in 2.6 ver.